# PHP / MSSQL String to HEX

Tags: php, sql-server, string, hex

After 5 hours of trying to get it to work, I decided to ask for help. My problem is PHP convert the different string to hex than MSSQL.

STRING

> đžćčšđđ

PHP

> bin2hex($data) // C491C5BEC487C48DC5A1C491C491

MSSQL

> CAST('đžćčšđđ' as varbinary) // F09EE6E89AF0F0

PHP result needs to be as MSSQL. What can I do to a solved problem?

EDIT 1

Almost got it to work correct, still 2 char is wrong

```
$unpacked = unpack('H*hex', mb_convert_encoding($data,'ISO-8859-2')); // F0BEE6E8B9F0F0
```

Comment: Those are are two differently encoded strings. The PHP string looks like UTF-8 and the MSSQL string is some single-byte encoding, probably a ISO8859-something, or a Microsoft variant.

Comment: When I set up in database čćžđš it selects fine but I cannot get the insert to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 10 hours of trying to get it full work, finally did it!! Posting solution if someone has a similar problem.

```
public function FixCroatianChars($data)
{
     $unpacked = unpack('H*hex', mb_convert_encoding($data, 'HTML-ENTITIES'));
     return 'CAST(0x' . $unpacked['hex'] . ' as char(' . strlen($unpacked['hex']) / 2 . '))';
}
```

Comment: Maybe in more recent versions of SQL Server HTML entities can be converted natively (without resorting to some shadowy XML decoding function), as it stands HTML entities cannot be decoded by SQL Server. That being said, good thinking with the dynamic length detection.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the MSSQL cast as varbinary, I recommend you do so.

Here's the PDO example:

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$myServer;Database=$myDB", $myUser, $myPass);
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT CAST(? as varbinary)');
$stmt->execute(array($lastname));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($result as $row) 
{
  // Note your result set will return example one row with one column in it
}
```

Even if you aren't using PDO, this should give you a general idea.

Comment: Thanks for your ANSWER, I already use PDO and my insert query look as 

INSERT INTO TICKETS (id,senderID,msg,sender,status) VALUES(CAST(0x3239 as char(2)),CAST(0x31 as char(1)),CAST(0x74657374 as char(4)),1,CAST(0x30 as char(1)))